# How to plot dataframe in the current state/sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to reconfigure a pandas dataframe, which currently looks like this:

```
   No. Val   
0  7   1  
1  9   2  
2  1   3  
3  4   4
```

The df has been sorted according to 'val' in ascending order. How can I go on to plot the df in the sequence of 'No.' column? (i.e first plot (7,1), then plot (9,2) etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matplotlib as

```
plt.plot( df['No.'].tolist() , df['Val'].tolist() , color ='blue' )
plt.show()
```

or seaborn as

```
sns.scatterplot(x = 'No.' , y = 'Val' , data = df)
```